# Using OnInit property in aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I added a user control in my MyDashboards.aspx page;

```
<uc:dlUC ID="dashboardListUserControl" runat="server" OnInit="ConfigureDashboardList" />
```

In MyDashboards.aspx.cs i.e. the code page, I have the following function:

```
public void ConfigureDashboardList(EventArgs e)
{}
```

I get the following error:

```
No overload for 'ConfigureDashboardList' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the sender parameter

```
public void ConfigureDashboardList(object sender,EventArgs e){}
```

Comment: Thanks. How do I find out which parameters the events like: OnInit need?

Comment: They are pretty much the same for standart page events.